# Не могу понять где выполняется подсветка элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализована подсветка активного элемента в меню. Судя по всему это не waypoint.

https://uvrvideo.ru/

Comment: При клике удаляется класс "active" с одного элемента li, и добавляется на другой элемент вот и вся подсветка

Comment: Я понимаю, где это реализовано в исходнике. Не могу найти строки которые за это отвечают.

Comment: А зачем? там все равно минифицированный код, мне кажется что это файл core.min.js, функция d.prototype.activateAnchor

Comment: Затем что на мою долю выпало исправить баг который там случился

Comment: А в теории я могу написать свой скрипт и подключить его позднее, чтобы перебить текущий скрипт

Comment: [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5264/186999)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строка 24108 style.css

```
.bg-transparent .rd-navbar-static .rd-navbar-nav > li.focus > a,
.bg-transparent .rd-navbar-static .rd-navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.bg-transparent .rd-navbar-static .rd-navbar-nav > li.active > a,
.bg-transparent .rd-navbar-fullwidth .rd-navbar-nav > li.focus > a,
.bg-transparent .rd-navbar-fullwidth .rd-navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.bg-transparent .rd-navbar-fullwidth .rd-navbar-nav > li.active > a {
    background-color: #F07C16;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

за элемент меню отвечает строка 24109

```
.bg-transparent .rd-navbar-static .rd-navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
```

Вы можете подключить после файла style.css свой файл, и там переопределить стили.